# Overriding a method that's in the superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass, overriding

I have a method set in my superclass...

```
 public void explain() {

     for (Item item: Instances) {
         System.out.println(item.getname + " is in location " + item.place):
     }
 }
```

I need to override this same method in the subclass to print out the original output message but the new instance for this method needs to print out different values that have been set in the subclass

I'm confused with the overriding bit (as I know little about it) and would like an explanation.

Comment: You can create the method in both classes, which one is called will depend on which kind of object you create/invoke the method from, the parent or the child

Comment: I think if you just write `getname` and `place` properly you'll get the result you're after. Is this in currently in the `item` class? And Instances is a static variable holding all instances of it?

Comment: I have set the explain method in the superclass and im trying to use the same one in my subclass but im calling the method from the superclass

Comment: I think at the end of the day, we need to know a little bit more about the classes to properly advise you on how to override(if needed at all).

Comment: @Cruncher what do you need to know and il try and explain?

Comment: @BobMarks I need to know what is `Item`, and what is `Instances`

Comment: public static ArrayList<Item> itemInstances = new ArrayList<>;

Comment: @Cruncher look at what i just said

Comment: @BobMarks is this method inside of the Item class?

Comment: @Cruncher yes the method explain is within the superclass. im trying to use the exact same method in the sub class and then when i do i can change the output.

Comment: @BobMarks You don't need to override this method then. So long as getname and place are set to the right values in the subclass, then this method will print them properly. I actually recommend making explain static.

Comment: The biggest thing, is that in the constructor for each subclass, you need to add the instance to your arraylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just give the method in base class parameter like

```
public void explain(Instances i)
```

and call it in your subclass. You don't need to override anything and have the benefit of code reuse from the base class. Or, in case some more complicated logic you can try [Template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) like

Base class

```
public abstract class Base {

    public abstract explain(Instances i);

    public void print(Item i) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Subclass

```
public class Subclass extends Base {

    @Override 
    public void explain(Instance instances) {
         //do some logic and call print in loop
         print(someItemfromInstances);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your subclass:

```
@override //Throw a warning if you're not overidding anything
public void explain(){
    super.explain();//This will call the method from the superclass.

     //Do what you have to do in the sub-class
}
```