# Extending a software package with small changes in some of the methodes

Tags: java, extend

I need to extend a java software package for a new algorithm. I've tested my changes by editing some of the classes in the package. Now I want to write extension classes that extend the original classes in the package and keep the main code intact. Changes are easy when I am adding methods to the main code.

But what should I do in this case?

```
class origin
{
        public a_method()
    {
        //Some code
    }
}


class example extends origin
{
        public a_method()
    {
        //Everything in the original method but very small changes
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping an electrician to learn java

Comment: I think this is a little bit harder than it looks.

Comment: You may be able to do what you want with [super](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html), but it has many limitations. You'll likely have to re-implement the method completely if ``super`` doesn't get it done.

Comment: Should I write the method with the same name again? Does it mean that I can copy/paste my edited version of the class with a new name as the extended version?

Comment: What kinds of "small changes" do you need to make? If you only need to add code before and/or after the code in the original method, then you can use `super.a_method()`. Otherwise, you probably need to do some refactoring and/or redesign.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding a method that's in the superclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548983/overriding-a-method-thats-in-the-superclass)

Answer (score 0):

Use the @Override annotation like so:

```
class Example extends Origin {
  @Override
  public a_method() {
    //Everything in the original method but very small changes
  }
}
```

I would recommend keeping the same method parameters and return values, lest things start to break.